# How to limit the items to a two items per row using flexbox in asp?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, sass, flexbox

I have an MVC project, where I have two columns. On the left column, I have a buttons grid, and I want to have it maximum to be two buttons per row. Currently, it is 4 buttons per row and I tried `flex: 0 1 50%` but that didn't work. Currently, it looks like this: [image: page buttons]

Here is the code for the buttons view inside the left column and the styles:

#### Grid.cshtml

```cs
<div class="linkContainer">
    <div class="linkContainer-grid">
        @foreach (var link in Model.Links)
        {
            <div class="linkContainer-gridItem">
                <a class="linkContainer-gridItem-link" href="@link.Url">
                    @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link.Icon))
                    {
                        <div><i class="icon @link.Icon"></i></div>
                    }
                    @link.Label
                </a>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

#### Grid.scss

```css
.linkContainer {
    padding: 1rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    position: relative;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #dddfe2;

    .linkContainer-title {
        color: #fff;
        background: $colorBrandDarkBlue;
        padding: 1rem;
        border-radius: 5px;
        margin: -.5rem -.5rem 1rem -.5rem;
    }

    .linkContainer-list {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;

        .linkContainer-item {
            position: relative;

            .linkContainer-link {
                display: -webkit-box;
                display: -ms-flexbox;
                display: flex;
                padding: .75rem .5rem;
                color: $colorBrandBlue;
                font-weight: 400;
                font-size: 18px;
                -webkit-box-align: center;
                -ms-flex-align: center;
                align-items: center;
                text-decoration: none;
                background-color: transparent;
                font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
            }

            .icon:before {
                font-size: 30px;
                margin-right: 1rem;
            }
        }

        .linkContainer-item:after {
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            border-top: 1px dotted;
            opacity: .25;
        }
    }

    .linkContainer-grid {
        padding: 0;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-family: "Montserrat",sans-serif;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: stretch;
        text-align: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;

        .linkContainer-gridItem {
            flex: 0 1 50%;
            padding: 20px 10px;
            background-color: $colorBrandBlue;
            border-radius: 25px;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            width: calc(50% - 20px);
            margin: 10px 0;
            min-width: 100px;
            max-width: 130px;

            .linkContainer-gridItem-link {
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

            .icon {
                font-size: 30px;
                margin-bottom: 0.25rem;
            }
        }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
        .linkContainer-grid {
            justify-content: center;

            .linkContainer-gridItem {
                margin: 10px;
            }
        }
    }
   
}
```

#### How can I make it two items per row whilst keeping the buttons the same size and alignments?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you set a `max-width` on your `.linkContainer-gridItem`, it will display all 4 items in a row, because flex box is trying to put as many items as possible in a row, before it has to wrap.

In order to put 2 items per row, the first step is to remove `min-width` and `max-width`. In fact, you can remove `width` as well because you can control it via `flex:`.

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/zv5tsrd1/22/

Now in order to display 2 items per row, you need to set the **total item width** to be `50%`. But the property `flex-basis:` as well as `width:` is just meant *content width*. This might be a good time to review the box model: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

We need to figure out the correct *content width* so that the **total item width**, including borders, paddings and margins, would be 50%:

content width = 50% - borders - paddings - margins

On break point less than 1024px, you have 10px padding left and right, so the *content width* of the item should be

```
.linkContainer-gridItem {
    flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 2*10px);
}
```

At break point 1024px and up, you have extra 10px margin left and right, so the *content width* of the item should be

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
    .linkContainer-grid {
        justify-content: center;

        .linkContainer-gridItem {
            flex-basis: calc(50% - 2*10px - 2*10px);
            margin: 10px;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/zv5tsrd1/27/

Comment: Can we keep the buttons the same width and height? For instance, the buttons are stretching to fill up the whole width, is there a way to make it a square all the time whilst being responsive?